# sdk manager doesnt load up but eclipse is set and everything else is fine

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, bundle, adt

I recently format my PC and now when I tried to install the ADT Bundle from the Android developers site, I can't open the SDK Manager.exe it just openes a blank command prompt and shuts down immediatly.
Also, when I try to launch the SDK Managr from eclipse it says "Starting Android SDK Manager", shows a progress bar (that moves) and than "Initialize ... SDK Manager will start up shoetly" but nothing happends.

Does somebody know what could be the problem? I am trying things since yesterday and I am hopeless.

Thanks from ahead :)

Answer (score 5):

My solution:

1. Modifying this file  [SDK HOME]\tools\android.bat
2. rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
   set java_exe="D:\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe"
3. "D:\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" is in your java sdk folder
   and delete this two line:
4. call lib\find_java.bat
   if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
5. restart IDE, OK.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences  then android and specify  the path of the android sdk . That will solve your problem .Adt is just confused about the location of the sdk .

Comment: No, I tried, and again, as i said, it opens a black cmd promp and then immediatly disappears

Answer (score 0):

maybe this question interests you [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038643/android-bat-opens-sdk-manager-sdk-manager-exe-does-not/15038759#15038759). My suggestion for him was to check if the adt and java are on the same bit system (both 32 bit or 64 bit). And maybe there will be post an answer which will help you.

Comment: I checked and all of them are 64bit (Like my system) and it i still not working

Comment: Than I can't help you. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Two causes for this that others report are

1) SDK can't find java so have to set it on PATH for system and

2) People have problems when path to java has spaces in the name

see [this stackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686633/android-sdk-manager-will-not-run).

Maybe you set the path before, after re-install java is in a different location and you need to set the environment again.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I got it resloved after adding path to `system32` folder into `PATH` environment variable.

If you are still facing the problem, try this solution.